# A finite abelian group $A$ can not be a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, projective-module

Any $\mathbb{Z}$-module $P$ is projective if it is a direct summand in *some* free $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$.

Now, if $M$ is some free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then $M \cong \bigoplus_{a \in A} \mathbb{Z}$ for some basis $A \subset M$. Now, we note that each summand has an countable infinite number of different elements, while $P$ is finite. I believe this constitutes a contradiction? I am trying to think of a way to argue it more precisely though, any suggestions? Actually, I believe the contradiction is that the direct sum (with $A$ as a summand) will have a non-zero element with finite order, while $M \cong \bigoplus_{a \in A} \mathbb{Z}$ has no non-zero element with finite order.

Any suggestions?

Comment: iirc a finitely generated module over a pid is projective iff it is free. Additionally, a finitely generated Abelian group is free iff it is torsion-free.

Comment: $A$ is not a group, it is a free abelian group basis, so it cannot be a summand. The fact that $A$ is a basis of $M$ means that $M=\bigoplus_{a\in A}\mathbb{Z}a$ where $\mathbb{Z}a$ is the infinite cyclic group generated by $a$.  The problem is that you are confusing the role of $A$. The set $A$ only indexes the summands, it is not a summand. Indeed, any element of $A$ except from $0$ is of infinite order in $M$.

Comment: "Each summand has a countable infinite number of different elements" doesn't quite do it, because direct sum decompositions need not be unique. Just because your group doesn't look like one of the ones in your sum decomposition does not mean it cannot be a direct summand (e.g., $\mathbb{Z}_2$ does not look like the unique summand in $\mathbb{Z}_6$, but it turns out that it is isomorphic to a direct summand of $\mathbb{Z}_6$). Instead, note that $M$ has no torsion, so it cannot have nontrivial finite submodules *at all*, let alone as direct summands.

Comment: I’ve edited my question, I accidentally put A where there should be a P.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin do you have an example of an isomorphism of two direct sums where one of the direct sums have a summand with only finitely many elements it can take, and the other has not?

Comment: I don’t think that would work, since there will be a well-defined projection from the summand that makes it finite, while the other sum will have no such projection.

Comment: No, I mean that just because the decomposition you have has summands with "different number of elements" than the module you have does not mean the module you have is not a direct summand. $\mathbb{Z}_6=\mathbb{Z}_6$ is a decomposition of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ into a direct sum of cyclic modules;  and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has a different number of elements than every direct summand in this decomposition. And yet, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ *is* (isomorphic to) a direct summand of $\mathbb{Z}_6$. So it's not just that they have a different number of elements (finite vs infinite). (cont)

Comment: If $A$ is projective, then any surjection $M \to A$ has a section. But $A$ is a finite $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so there's a surjection $\mathbb{Z}^n \to A$.

Comment: Yeah, that was not really my argument. My argument was about the difference between finite and infinite cardinality in the the summands of the two sums.

Comment: (cont) So there's actually more than just "this is finite, all those are infinite". It's the fact that these modules do not have nontrivial finite submodules... which means you don't have to go through saying "Oh, these are all infinite, and the one I have is finite, so they can't work", which is incomplete at best. Just point out that your $M$ has *no* nontrivial finite submodules.

Comment: And yes, there are examples of modules with direct sum decompositions where one of them has infinite direct summands and the other has finite direct summands: just take $\oplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong A\oplus B$, where $A$ and $B$ are both a countable direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Hm, yes. Point taken. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if $A=0$ then $A$ is projective and finite.  Otherwise, all you really need to show is that any nonzero submodule of a free abelian group is infinite.

Comment: A projective Abelian group is torsion-free (because submodules of torsion free modules are torsion free). Finite groups are clearly not torsion free.